# Addon Duplicate files - which to remove?

Tags: add-on

I searched for a similar topic but I might just be looking in the wrong place.

I have two addons added to 2.79b, still using it for many purposes, and have already upgraded to the latest 2.8 build, however these addons are not yet upgraded to work on 2.8.

Anyway, I forgot that I had a version of one of these addons installed already, set it up, realized it was already installed, and removed it.

Restarted Blender and went to use addon, it wasn't there.  Went to add addon, and I got a warning that the addon is installed in two places, C drive Program files, and the Root drive where the addon is located.

If these are two opposing files that are conflicting with one another for the addon to run, which should I remove, the one in the C drive, or the Root drive version?

I think this has happened to me before long ago and when I removed one of the versions, I was never able to get it to run after that.

Thank you for any help you can offer, or point me to the question on the stack exchange that was previously asked so I am not creating a redundancy here.

Comment: When you remove addon installed twice it's only important which one of them is newer to provide you with recent features. It doesn't matter if you remove one located in default location or custom one. It's not really clear from the question how the addon is told by Blender to be installed twice though since you removed it from one place already; make sure to clean up everything after version you removed and leave in place the other one

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I will try this tonight.